# finding distinct rows in dataset using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the below query to find the distinct rows from a dataset but its not getting me the distinct for example its not removing the duplicate and show me the distinct count.

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in _dsMechanic.Tables[0].Rows
                                select new { col1 = dRow["colName"] }).Distinct();
```

Comment: it should ignore letter case and show the distinct pls help

Comment: If you want to know how many went into each group, you need to use groups, not distinct.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var distinctRows = (
    from DataRow dRow in _dsMechanic.Tables[0].Rows
    select dRow["colName"]).
    Distinct();
```

Doing the distinct on an anonymous type is just asking for trouble.